# Upload/ Download buttons are not working in android WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

So I am trying to make an App for my friend's website using android WebView client.
Everything runs fine but the upload and download buttons are not responding.

Also I would like to know how can I show the specific parts in card view.

I am new to it and I know I must be sounding like a stupid.

So any suggestions?

Comment: post some of the code you've tried

Comment: Hi @Nawaz, and welcome to StackOverflow. 
Each and every user is important and don't think you're stupid!
However, as a rule of thumb, it would help other users if you show us what you have done up-to now. ie: Your code. Please try to provide us with much information as possible as it would attract more users!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Can you attach your code?
If you want to use customized buttons, you have to add clickListener on Button and do somethings what you want in onClick() in clickListener.